# Enable INotifyPropertyChanged for Property in Library class

Tags: c#, events, properties, inotifypropertychanged

I would like to get notified when a property in a class of a library changes (to be specific, when the `SerialPort.IsOpen` property changes). Is there any way to attach a `INotifyPropertyChanged` call to the property from the outside?

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SerialPort.IsOpen));`? But you have to have a `SerialPort` reference in class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Short answer: no. If you don't have access to the code and can change it, there is no way get an event when that property changes. Longer answer: I'm sure there are frameworks to do this kind of "interception" (I think that was the word), like profilers and things like that use to measure runtime of methods etc... but that's not a good thing to have in productive code as it slows down your code significantly.